# What is UInt8Array() max value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typed-arrays

```js
// Storing array and targeting HTML elements.
var array = new Uint8Array(1),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  // Get random values from the array.
  number = window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  // Show value on the front-end.
  output.innerHTML = number[0];
};
```

```css
h1, button {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 175px;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="output">Click to go random.</h1>

<button id="btn">Randomize</button>
```

I've been experimenting with `UInt8Array()` method in Javascript to create random number. When used with `window.crypto.getRandomValues()`, it works even better than `Math.random()`.

However I would like to know what's the max value this method could generate, so I was wondering if someone more experienced could give this information and perhaps explain me how this works and how this maximum value is defined. Also, can I use these numbers and store them in a variable?

Comment: I'm really curious and hope you'll answer this question: _How in the world_ are you using a UInt8Array method to generate random numbers? That is some serious off-label use.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, would you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: @szupie @Gus Ortiz I apologize, only now I've seen your questions. I've edited the question and added a jsfiddle as requested to explain that.

Probably there are easier ways to do it but this is the way that I've found when I want a number bigger than `255`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) of the method says:

> The Uint8Array typed array represents *an array of 8-bit unsigned
>   integers.* The contents are initialized to 0 ..

This means that the highest value is 2^8 - 1 meaning 255.

Calculated in JS as `Math.pow(2, 8);`

Comment: Continuing with @user2864740's clarification, if you want a typed array that will set an element as 255 if you give it a value over 2^8, you'd want `Uint8ClampedArray`.

Comment: That's what I though of so for an array of **16-bit** unsigned integers the highest value would be **65535**? If so I got it now! Thank you so much for your help guys, this really helped me understand more about this language and IT in general.

@GusOrtiz

Comment: That's correct cs.almeida, and when you are talking about signed integers then it changes to a range between  -(2^X-1) and (2^X-1)

Comment: I'm still curious about how you managed to generate random numbers with Uint8Array!

Comment: Like this 
`window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(length))`